# Парсинг html страницы. Как извлечь два значения между тегами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

```
<html>
.....
<tr.........
<tr bgcolor="#d3d3d3"><td>Last Week:<td><font color="darkblue">98076543788965678</font><td>Last Month:<td><font color="darkblue">094789462378651234</font>
</html>
```

Как выташить значения 98076543788965678 и 094789462378651234

Comment: Для разбора HTML есть очень мощная библиотека: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.ru/bs4ru.html

Comment: Но это какой-то кривой `html`. У вас `<td>` каждый раз только открывается и ни разу не закрывается через `</td>`, так не должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

При помощи библиотеки re.

- `import re`
- `pattern = r"Last\sWeek:\D+(\d{5,})</font>\D+(\d{5,})</font>`
- `match = re.search(pattern, строка/переменная типа str в которой ищем элемент по шаблону pattern)`
- `if match:`
- `....print(match.group(1))` #98076543788965678
- `....print(match.group(2))`
  #094789462378651234

---

В вопросе действительно неверно указаны html-теги
А вообще, существует замечательная библиотека bs4)